# Highpass and lowpass filter phase-shifted by 90°

Tags: low-pass, phase-shift, high-pass-filter

If I wanted to build a circuit that consists of an highpass filter and a lowpass filter, what should I consider if I wanted to ensure, that their exits are phase-shifted by 90°?

Comment: The question is a little strange if you've ever looked at the phase of a low and high pass filter. What's your goal with this?

Comment: It'll be completely different questions whether you ask for all frequencies shifted by 90 degrees or a particular frequency shifted by 90 degrees.

Comment: @user3528438 It should not be frequency dependent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what should I consider if I wanted to ensure, that their exits are
>   phase-shifted by 90°?

This is a problem facing relatively wideband I and Q circuits when trying to phase shift a modulated carrier in order to properly use IQ demodulation techniques.

The simple way is to feed your input to a circuit like this: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO0QMg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And choose R = R1 = R2 = \$\sqrt{L/C}\$. This ensures that OUT1 and OUT2 have a phase differential of 90 degrees across all frequencies.

So, with L = 250 nH and C = 100 pF, R = 50 ohms.

You need to scale L and C to suit the part of the spectrum you wish to use. With L and C as shown, it is optimized for a centre frequency of about 32 MHz (Fc = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$)

> It should not be frequency dependent

The phase relationship between OUT1 and OUT2 is always 90 degrees but amplitudes do change with frequency as with any high-pass or low-pass fliter. Why not use a sim tool and check it out.